# A way to solve nonsmooth stiff ODEs

Tags: numerics, ode, newton-method, interior-point-method

Let us considered the following ODEs
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{dX}{dt} = F(X), \tag{1.1}
\end{align*}
where the unknown $X\in \mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^l$ and it can be stiff. These ODEs can be solved numerically by classical Newton's method if $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere on the considered domain
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{X^{n+1}-X^n}{\Delta t} = F\left(X^{n+1}\right).
\end{align*}
In cases of $F$ is not differentiable everywhere, I have read in a lecture that there is a way to solve numerically by replacing the system (1.1) with the following system
\begin{align*}
    X^{n+1} - X^n - (1-\nu)\Delta t F(X^{n+1}) & = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^l\tag{1.2a}\\
    \det\left[I - (1-\nu)\Delta t \nabla F(X^{n+1}) \right] - w &= 0 \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1.2b} \\
    \min(\nu,w) &= 0 \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1.2c}
\end{align*}
where $\nu$ and $w$ are two new unknowns to be sought for simultaneously to $X^{n+1}$. I wonder how they can do like this and what is technique they use?

Comment: Can you give a link to where you read this?

Comment: If $F$ is not differentiable, then $\nabla F$ in (1.2b) doesn't exist either.

Comment: Perhaps making $\nu=1$ at those points where $\nabla F$ does not exist is the strategy there. Looks like some kind of regularization, replacing the original problem by something close to it but with a differentiable RHS.

Comment: @MaximUmansky If you choose $\nu=1$ at these points, then (1.2b) boils down to $\text{det}[I]-w=0$, so $w=l$ ($l$=size of the vector $X$). But then (1.2c) isn't satisfied. This whole set of equations doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth But 1.2c just says that the minimum for $(\nu,w)$ on the domain is zero, at a particular point $w$ can be $l$ (or any real number larger than zero) - am I wrong about this?

Comment: @MaximUmansky The last equation expresses a complementarity condition between $\nu$ and $w$. So I think we can separate the problem into two cases: $\nu=0$ and $\nu>0$.  If $\nu = 0$ in the solution of the above system, then we have succeeded in keeping the full time-step while preserving the solution on the “right” side of the states, where the determinant remains non-negative. If $\nu > 0$ in the solution, this implies
that we cannot achieve the full time-step but have to stop before.

Comment: I also think this is a regularization technique but how can we do that is the thing I am wondering now. It is quite strange to me.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth BTW, isn't it true that det$[I]$=1?

Comment: @MaximUmansky Ah yes, determinant, not trace. You're right. But the point is that if $\nu=1$, then $w=1$ and so the complementarity condition is not satisfied.